# Naivebayes MultinomialNB scikit-learn/sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am bulding a naive bayes classifier and I follow the tutorial on the scikit-learn website.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import csv
import string
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Importing dataset
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True,error_bad_lines=False)
df2 = data.set_index("name", drop = False)



df2['sentiment'] = df2['rating'].apply(lambda rating : +1 if rating > 3 else -1)


train, test = train_test_split(df2, test_size=0.2)


count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(traintrain['review'])
test_matrix = count_vect.transform(testrain['review'])

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, train['sentiment'])
```

The first argument is the vocabulary dictionary and it returns a Document-Term matrix. 
What should be the second argument,twenty_train.target?

**Edit** Data example

```
Name, review,rating
film1,......,1
film2, the film is....,5 
film3, film about..., 4
```

with this instruction I created a new column , if the rating is >3 so the review is positive, else it is negative

```
df2['sentiment'] = df2['rating'].apply(lambda rating : +1 if rating > 3 else -1)
```

Comment: The second argument should be the class labels which you want your model to learn. Are you not sure what your targets are? Can you explain what you want to do to the data, what do you want the model to learn? If you are not sure about these questions, I would recommend you read more about machine learning.

Comment: no I am sure, it is the polarity of the review for film, positive or negative, my data contain 3 filed name,review,rating, I add a 4th one that contain the polarity

Comment: Then whats `'sentiment'` you have here? And why are you training the tfidfvectorizer on multiple columns? It will give wrong results.

Comment: @VivekKumar: I edited the post, sentiment is the polarity positive or negative, I train only on the column review

Comment: The code doesnt show that you train only on review. Currently you are sending the full `df2` to `train_test_split` and then use that to train `CountVectorizer` which means it uses all df2. Not just `'reviews'`

Comment: sorry it is a typo train['review']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fit` method of `MultinomialNB` expects as input the `x` and `y`.
Now, `x` should be the training vectors (training data) and `y` should be the target values.

```
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
```

---

**In more detail:**

```
X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is 
the number of features.

y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
Target values.
```

Note: Make sure that `shape = [n_samples, n_features]` and `shape = [n_samples]` of `x` and `y` are defined correctly. Otherwise, the `fit` will throw an error.

---

**Toy example:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc',
              'comp.graphics', 'sci.space']

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                                      categories=categories)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
# the following will be the training data
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
vectors.shape

newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',
                                     categories=categories)
# this is the test data
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)

clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)

# the fitting is done using the TRAINING data
# Check the shapes before fitting
vectors.shape
#(2034, 34118)
newsgroups_train.target.shape
#(2034,)

# fit the model using the TRAINING data
clf.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)

# the PREDICTION is done using the TEST data
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
```

### **EDIT:**

The `newsgroups_train.target` is just a `numpy` array that contains the `labels (or targets or classes)`.

```
import numpy as np

newsgroups_train.target
array([1, 3, 2, ..., 1, 0, 1])

np.unique(newsgroups_train.target)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

So in this example we have 4 different classes/targets.

This variable is needed in order to fit a classifier.

Comment: what i did not understand is what is newsgroups_train.target! how to build this, or what is the function target? in my case I only have a training file, I don't use a predifined file, should i create a new file?

Comment: in my case i will predict tow classes 0 (negatif) and 1 (postive), so the target is the sentiment column and I have MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_counts, train['sentiment'])

Comment: then yes. I agree. consider accepting and upvoting my answer.